# Japanese SO posts appearing in SO filtered feeds

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, rss

I just found a link in my filtered questions that comes from [ja.stackoverflow.com](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/)

[image]

I did not ask for jp posts, because I cannot understand them.  Why are they appearing in my question feed?

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/12/stack-overflow-in-japanese/

Comment: Ah, thanks. A search on Meta for "jp.stackoverflow.com" did not return any thing useful. Wonder why ...

Comment: Do you read/write Japanese well enough to understand that question?  If not, you may want to complain about it appearing in your question list.  If not, I guess the system is working fine, though it's a bit strange you are receiving Japanese questions (apparently) without requesting them.

Comment: my sentiments exactly. I did not ask for jp posts, because I cannot understand them. So where do I go to "complain" or file a bug?  I guess I also was surprised that the jp forum even exists. I have seen comms about the Brazilian Portuguese spin-off, but I've never seen any mention of a Japanese spin-off. Thanks for pointing me to the blog post.Lovely comments.

Comment: I edited this question to be a [bug].  If you have any more details to add to the report, please edit them in.

Answer (score 19):

[Your FavTags filter](https://stackexchange.com/filters/75280/favtags) is configured to list all questions tagged with "excel" on **All Sites**.

The Japanese question is tagged with "excel", so it appears in your filtered list.

Comment: Is anyone aware of an easy way to create a FavTags filter for the StackExchange sites in English?

Comment: If we introduce other languages into the mix, and if these languages use the same tags, like `Excel`, then it would be really cool if we could create filters for just the languages we understand.  The topic, like "Excel"  can contain a raft of questions in languages I don't speak. I only want to see "Excel" questions in English or German, but not in Portuguese or Japanese.  Any thoughts how this could be achieved with filters that go across the network?

Comment: @teylyn: There’s an old [feature request for excluding sites from a filter](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/90289/193139), but without any kind of response from the SE team.

Comment: thanks for that link. I've added a comment to it.

Comment: current behaviour makes no sense. I don't think anybody is interested in results in all the possible languages.

Comment: @teylyn why not search for excel on SO, SU, etc. instead of all sites?

Comment: @Braiam, The information he's looking for might be general in nature and cover several SE sites. But one would still only expect the results to be in a language you'd actually understand.

Comment: @Braiam, what ouflak says. I have a filter on all `Excel` tags across the network. It worked fine until recently. The specific language sites are the new component in the mix.I cannot possibly know which sites have an `Excel` tag, so I search all of them. That worked fine while all sites were in English. Now we have sites in other languages. I still don't know which "English" language sites have the `Excel` tag. I'm after an easy way to see Excel questions on all sites that use my preferred language without having to specify individual sites. New sites pop up all the time.

Comment: @ouflak That's exactly what I'm after. And just FYI I'm a "she" not a "he".

Comment: @teylyn it's working fine *right now*. If you didn't see ja.so tagged questions, then there is a problem. I don't see why you don't just deselect which sites you don't want the feed to watch.

Comment: @Braiam: Exluding/deselecting specific sites is not possible, that’s what the linked [feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/90289/193139) is for. You either have to add sites explicitly and manually (which, of course, is not a good solution if you want most of the current 133 sites, including those new to come), or you set it to "All Sites".

Comment: @unor what?! [I can select all but 1 site](http://i.stack.imgur.com/GQFC3.png). How you say is not possible? (oh, btw, it took me just 20 seconds and a couple of tab/space strokes to make it possible)

Comment: @Braiam: I can’t reproduce this. When I select "Just these sites", it only shows sites that currently have this tag.

Comment: @unor just select the sites first and fill the tag field later

Comment: @Braiam: As soon as I select a tag, the site list updates (and all sites that don’t have this tag disappear).